# Errors exporting model to .pmx (multiple plugins) and .x

Tags: export

[image]

[image]

I keep getting nonetype errors Trying to export a model with multiple plugins
It wont even let me export it as .x with out an error what am I doing wrong? Just getting one to work is enough for me.

Comment: sorry, what format is .pmx, or .x ? which exporting addon are you using? which kinf of object are you trying to export, can you show it in blender?

Comment: Im using mmd_tools and i installed Pymeshio in desperation. I cant even get it to export with the direct x plugin that comes with blender. Heres a picture of what Im exporting  https://imgur.com/a/2rrhU

Comment: .pmx Is a model type recognized by a program called MMD. But I cant even get it to export as .x

Comment: About non-bundled export plugins you could show which versions are you using and where we can get those, exactly, to maybe replicate the problem. I can export the default cube using the bundled "import-export Dirext X format", without errors, so maybe is an issue with your model. If you can share it (or part of it) use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then paste the provided link in you question text or comments...

Comment: I just put it up on the stack exchange I also just noticed im having an issue with the normals flipping over?  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3940" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3940/)

Comment: Welcome to bse, Lotte.  You have a number of empty material slots.  (show as icon only, no material associated) try removing these before export.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do so? I read somewhere that opening and closeing the file is supposes to rid of them. But it hasent for me.